# decouple colorbar from figure matlab

Tags: matlab, colorbar, colormap

Is it possible to change the color of the colorbar without changing the color of the figure?

```
figure_1 = figure;
j1= bar(rand(2,10),'stacked');
colormap(winter)
htx = colorbar('SouthOutside');
colormap(jet)
```

In particular I would like to have the object in the figures colored with the colormap winter and the colorbar following the colormap jet...is it possible to decouple the 2?

Comment: Would that help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101346-how-do-i-use-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two FileExchange functions that I've used for this purpose with satisfactory results. [freezeColors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors---unfreezecolors), which is mentioned in the link that @Benoit_11 gave in his comment will let you have two or more subplots in one figure with different colormaps, but the colorbars have to be difficult, and `freezeColors` ignores them. For that you need [COLORMAP and COLORBAR utilities](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24371-colormap-and-colorbar-utilities--jul-2014-), and in particular `cbfreeze` which will fix the colorbar and keep it from changing.

So your code would look like this:

```
figure_1 = figure;
j1= bar(rand(2,10),'stacked');
colormap(winter)
freezeColors;

htx = colorbar('SouthOutside');
colormap(jet)
cbfreeze(htx);
```